# How to set two tabular environments, horizontally aligned, to the width needed for the larger?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

As part of a larger display, I am placing two tabular environments together, one above the other.  These two environments are going to appear in one column of a larger tabular, and I want the two environments to have the same width.  I  would prefer not to use `tabular*`, because I don't want to have to guess the width and keep adjusting it as the contents change.

I tried setting them in a single `tabular`, but then both columns got too wide, making the total both too wide and unpleasant to read.  In other words, it won't do have both tables share a first column, because that column will be too wide for the first table to be readable.  And they can't share a second column, because the second table won't really have room for a second column of that width.

However, if they have the same *total* width, everything should look good.  But I don't know how to find that total width other then playing guessing games with `tabular*` and explicit widths.

Is there a way to change the following MWE so that the second table is set to the width of the first table?  (With suitable `\extracolsep`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center} 

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\multicolumn2{c}{(a) Names}\\[\medskipamount]
\toprule
$x, f$&Name of a variable (or function)\\
$X$& Name of a module\\
$K$& Name of a value constructor\\
$t$& Name of a type\\
$T$& Name of a module type\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\\
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\strut\\
\multicolumn2{c}{(b) Declarations in the theory}\\[\medskipamount]
\toprule
\mbox{(abstype $t$)}&$t :: *$ or $t :: * \mathrel @ \pi$\\
\mbox{(type $t$ $\tau$)}&$t = \tau$\\
\mbox{(val $x$ $\tau$)}&$x : \tau$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: example of two tables]

Comment: Similar question: [Table with two tabulars of different width](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/508751/134144)

Comment: @leandriis Thanks for the pointer (search didn't turn that one up), but that doesn't solve the problem.  (You'll note that the answer to that question still exhibits the problem I'm trying to solve.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd set the captions and the rules in the outer (main) `tabular` and use two inner `tabular`s for the actual data:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{}}
  \multicolumn{1}{@{} c @{}}{(a) Names} \\[\medskipamount]
  \toprule
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
    $x, f$ & Name of a variable (or function) \\
    $X$    & Name of a module                 \\
    $K$    & Name of a value constructor      \\
    $t$    & Name of a type                   \\
    $T$    & Name of a module type
  \end{tabular} \\
  \bottomrule \\[\dimexpr-\normalbaselineskip+\bigskipamount]
  \multicolumn{1}{@{} c @{}}{(b) Declarations in the theory} \\[\medskipamount]
  \toprule
  \begin{tabular}{@{} l l @{}}
    (abstype $t$)     & $t :: *$ or $t :: * \mathrel{@} \pi$ \\
    (type $t$ $\tau$) & $t = \tau$                           \\
    (val $x$ $\tau$)  & $x : \tau$
  \end{tabular} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oooh!  Clever!  Why didn't I think of that??

Answer (score 2):

REVISED: Here it is, *WITHOUT* `tabular*`.

I took the OP's MWE and enclosed the larger width `tabular` portion in its own sub-`tabular`, using `\multicolumn` to place it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center} 

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\multicolumn2{c}{(a) Names}\\[\medskipamount]
\toprule
\multicolumn2{@{}c@{}}{\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
$x, f$&Name of a variable (or function)\\
$X$& Name of a module\\
$K$& Name of a value constructor\\
$t$& Name of a type\\
$T$& Name of a module type\\
\end{tabular}}\\
\bottomrule
\strut\\
\multicolumn2{c}{(b) Declarations in the theory}\\[\medskipamount]
\toprule
\mbox{(abstype $t$)}&$t :: *$ or $t :: * \mathrel @ \pi$\\
\mbox{(type $t$ $\tau$)}&$t = \tau$\\
\mbox{(val $x$ $\tau$)}&$x : \tau$\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With nested tabulars:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center} 

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\multicolumn2{c}{(a) Names}\\[\medskipamount]
\toprule
$x, f$&Name of a variable (or function)\\
$X$& Name of a module\\
$K$& Name of a value constructor\\
$t$& Name of a type\\
$T$& Name of a module type\\
\bottomrule
\strut\\
\multicolumn2{c}{(b) Declarations in the theory}\\[\medskipamount]
\toprule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\mbox{(abstype $t$)}&$t :: *$ or $t :: * \mathrel @ \pi$\\
\mbox{(type $t$ $\tau$)}&$t = \tau$\\
\mbox{(val $x$ $\tau$)}&$x : \tau$\\
\end{tabular}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```